# This application, or a library it uses, is using NSQuickDrawView, which has been deprecated. Apps should cease use of QuickDraw and move to Quartz

Tags: android

how can we solve this types of the error -> "This application, or a library it uses, is using NSQuickDrawView, which has been deprecated. Apps should cease use of QuickDraw and move to Quartz."

Answer (score 22):

This is a problem with Mac OSX and the Eclipse Android emulators. There is nothing wrong with your code. It seems to happen at it's own whim. I find that starting the emulator on its own (Window>Android SDK and AVD Manager, select the emulator and click Start...) and then running the build once the emulator is online seems to eliminate it, but this could be pure superstition. Nonetheless, it will work on your Mac if she is in the right mood.

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/f10995f2a829229d

Answer (score 1):

This is a probleme with osx Emulator.

You can ignore this warning but to test your app you must:
1-launch your emulator by running your app (you will have warning message)
2- wait for emulator to start completly
3
. Since emulator and wait for it to start and then relaunch your app.